# How to run testng xml using gradle?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, build.gradle, geb

I am trying to run testng.xml using gradle task but looks like its not picking it. Can someone please help me in identifying what I am missing here? Do I need to pass the path of testng.xml somewhere?

```
build.gradle 

    test {
        useTestNG {
            useDefaultListeners = true   
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using suites to specify your xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to tell gradle where your TestNG suite xml is located if you want it to use one. Assuming that your test.xml file is located inside of `src/test` directory of your project it would look like this:

```
test {
    useTestNG {
        suites "src/test/testng.xml"
    }
}
```